# Issues after Migration to RC4 in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am facing few issues after migration from Beta-17 to RC4. I am getting the below compilation errors

Bootstrap Error

```
/// < reference path="../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts" >
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser';
Error: Module "../platform-browser/index" as no exported member bootstrap
```

Router Error

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from '@angular/router';
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/router'
```

I tried with router-deprecated as well, still getting the module not found error

```
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/router-deprecated'
```

If the existing router is deprecated, then what is the new way of implementing routing?

I verified in the following [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) URL, but not able to notice much of difference.

Can anyone share some light on this?

**Updated as per the comments: New set of Errors**

I am able to import both bootstrap and the router now, but I am getting some other errors

Error# 1.  Not able to import RouteConfig

```
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig } from '@angular/router';
Error: Module "../angular/router/index has no exported member RouteConfig"
```

In order to make the **router-deprecated** to work i.e. my existing implementation of the routes, I need to import **RouteConfig**.
I am not sure from where can I import **RouteConfig**

2. Apart from this, I am getting almost 210 compilation errors like below. when I searched for the below errors, it is suggested to add the following line

   /// ../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

But as part of migration I have already added the below line

```
/// < reference path="../node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api/typings/browser.d.ts" >
```

Errors:

```
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\async.d.ts 34  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\async.d.ts 35  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   9   Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   15  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   16  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   17  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   17  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   18  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   18  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   19  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   19  Active
Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'Promise'. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\promise.d.ts   20  Active


Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\repeat.d.ts   2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\retry.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\retryWhen.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\sample.d.ts   2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\sampleTime.d.ts   2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\scan.d.ts 2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\share.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\single.d.ts   2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\skip.d.ts 2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\skipUntil.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\skipWhile.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\startWith.d.ts    2   Active
Error   TS2664  Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found. TypeScript Virtual Projects ..\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\subscribeOn.d.ts  2   Active
```

Comment: While it looks as if Krishnan the code working now, I've seen the ES2664 Invalid module name with the Observable module using Visual Studio 2015 (update 3), apparently also present in update 2 & VS2013 - which in my case was due to a VS TypeScript tools issue, and the following URL has a workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, try getting your bootstrap function from:

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

Secondly, the new router has a totally new API which means you'll be importing different modules from it when you get it working and it works completely different to the deprecated version. Might be best to try and get the `router-deprecated` version working first as your beta.17 version of the project will be mostly in line with the deprecated router.

The issue with not finding either router module appears as though you to have not set up your loader mappings and/or typings and/or tsconfig correctly. Check the contents of your `package.json` and your the config of your loader (SystemJS / webpack) against the tour of heroes version as a start. I've found that for upgrading ng2 versions, this is the best way as the documentation is quite difficult to find and follow for upgrading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have updated as per your comments, but now getting different set of errors, please refer the updated section in my query

Comment: To get the deprecated router working you need to use `import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';`. The new router uses totally different components. i.e. There is no longer a `RouteConfig` but a `RouterConfig` which works totally differently. You'll need to change the format of how you construct your routes and namely your `[routerLink]`s. Thats why I'm suggesting getting everything else sorted using the deprecated router first, then look to update to the new router when you know everything is RC4 compliant.

Comment: I am able to resolve these router and browser errors, but still there are around 246 errors on Cannot find name 'Promise' and Cannot find name 'Map'. Can you please help me in resolving these issues?

Comment: The issue is that, in package.json and in index.html, es6-shim.min.js is included. the "target" property under "compilerOptions" to be set to "es6" in the tsconfig.json.
This fix has solved the cannot find promise/map issue

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the great advice from Ian, I have a sample application that I just converted to RC 4 that may help. You can find it [here](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM%20-%20Final%20Updated).

[Here](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/commit/41637545c34405250182f60b06ad30bafe598232) is the commit with the relevant changes.

Comment: Cheers DeborahK! That application is the best example app that I've seen of Angular2. So many examples try to be 'starters' with all the bells and whistles instead of just being simple, good examples. Your repo a great resource.

Comment: Thank you! Glad it was useful.